# Gitflow merge features with protected develop branch

Tags: git, git-flow

So basically I'm following the GitFlow model, and I am liking it very much so far.

However, I still have some questions when it comes to a protected develop branch.

No one should be able to push code directly to develop, only review merge requests and reject/accept them.

When I create a new feature, I do:

[image: new feature]

And okay, my branch is created. After I'm done producing code, I can:

[image: finish feature]

And then I can't simply push my local develop branch to the remote one, since it is protected.
So I simply do:

[image]

Then the code reviewer (I'll be the code reviewer but I just want to understand the whole process) accepts the merge request in GitLab, and I have to manually delete the local my-merge-request branch.

So to try to solve this little setback, instead of finishing the feature, I push it using git push instead, create the merge request, and after the request is accepted I try to finish the feature using git flow feature finish.

[image]

[image]

However it says that no remote version of the branch could be found, so I have to manually checkout to another branch, and do git branch -D feature/foo.

I'm finding both methods a little cumbersome. Is there any extra step I'm missing on to how to create a MERGE REQUEST from my local develop (after I finish a feature) and not push it directly to the remove develop?

Or maybe make it so my feature branch which got pushed in the second option above gets automatically deleted once the MERGE REQUEST is accepted, since I can't do git flow feature finish because the branch gets deleted from the remote repository.

I've tried searching for similar problems but couldn't find anything that quite fits what I'm facing.

Comment: Are you not working on a forked repo? Ideally, you should be creating pull requests from the forked repo branch (feature branch) to the develop branch of the original repo.

Comment: Oh, it is a very small team but I do want to start using good practices...
We're not using forked repos atm, just one repo where I'm the only one that has access to the develop and master branches (even though I also use features and never push to develop or master)

Comment: This is the step that you are missing at the moment. If everyone uses forked repos, they can push to their forked repo's develop branches without any problem, and then create a pull request from their forked/develop to upstream/develop branch. This is how the ideal workflow should be. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! That would solve everything. Thank you so much for your help! I've really tried searching git-flow "flow" on the web, but didn't find anything about this specific issue.

Comment: Thanks is not a solution. When you merge feature-1 to your fork develop and create pull request, and then again work on another feature-2 and merge that to your fork develop. Existing pull request for feature-1 will be updated with feature-2 changes as well. Which is not ideal